# Minimal BPEL/BPMN requirement?

Tags: java, bpel, bpmn

I'm new to BPEL/BPMN.

Is it possible to write a BPEL/BPMN aware software without WS-* web services and EJB Container such as jBoss, WebLogic, Glassfish?

I want to know if there are quickstart tutorials on creating BPEL/BPMN programs with Maven and Eclipse.

And, do open engines like Apache ODE and jBPM provide WYSIWYG workflow designer to end users behind browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BPEL itself is depending on WS-*, so if you want to use standard BPEL, you cannot avoid Web Services. BPMN 2.0 however provides an abstraction, which means you can use BPMN with WS-*, Java or whatever you want as long as your engine supports that. Activiti for instance is bad in WS-* but quite good when you want to embed it into your Java app.

The Eclipse BPEL designer has a deployment descriptor editor and deployer for Apache ODE and JBoss Riftsaw, the latter is basically ODE with some JBoss foo.

Comment: Correct - and you can use Intalio|BPMS if you want to design your process with BPMN, and have it deploy BPEL to Apache ODE.

Answer (score 1):

you can no doubt create clients that connect to a BPEL engine yet don't run within an application server.
They will however need WS-* because that's the mechanism to communicate with BPEL processes.

For tutorials, see the websites of the various vendors of BPEL related tools and servers.
jBoss I think has a plugin for Eclipse to provide a workflow editor, I don't know about Apache.